# Pandas: Create a column with column values based on a priority

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
   id  price1  price2 price_col1 price_col2
0   1   100.0     NaN     price1     price2
1   2   200.0     NaN     price2     price1
```

Here, the columns `price_col1` and `price_col2` contain column names present within the same dataframe. For example in this case `price1` and `price2`.

My use case is that for each row I get all the price columns and assign the price value based on whether it is null or not

So the desired output would be:

```
df
   id  price1  price2 price_col1 price_col2 price_val
0   1   100.0     NaN     price1     price2   100.0
1   2   200.0     NaN     price2     price1   200.0
```

Here for the first row I assign `price_val = 100` (equal to `price1`) as the priority in this case is `price1`,`price2`. For the second row I assign `price_val=200` (equal to `price1` again) based on the priority `price2`,`price1`.

Basically I need to stop as soon as I encounter a not null value.

This can be achieved using pandas apply but the performance will take a hit when the data is in millions.

Any suggestions on how this can be done without using pandas apply?

Solution using pandas apply:

```
def calculate_price(row):

    df = pd.DataFrame(row).transpose()
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('price_col')]

    row['price_col_list'] = ''
    for col in columns:
        if row[col] != '' and not pd.isna(row[col]):
            row['price_col_list'] += row[col] + ','
    price_columns = row['price_col_list'].split(',')
    price_columns = list(filter(None, price_columns))
    row['price_val'] = np.NaN
    for price_column in price_columns:
        if not pd.isna(row[price_column]):
            row['price_val'] = row[price_column]
        else:
            continue
    return row['price_val']

df['price_val'] = df.apply(calculate_price,axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using with apply?  It will be easier for others to help provide a non-apply based solution if it's totally clear how your current solution is working.

Comment: I am not sure to follow your "priority" rule. In particular what do you mean by 
"I need to stop as soon as I encounter a not null value. "

Comment: If I understand correctly, we can disregard `price_col1` and  `price_col2`? Maybe you should remove them from your example? Either way, you should really edit this post to make it more clear

Comment: The column names for the actual price columns price1 and price2 are present in price_col1 and price_col2.Editing the question with the solution i have created using pandas apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this would do:

```
# this is to search for the first non-null
s = df[['price1','price2']].ffill(1).stack()

# looking for the correct order
u = (df.filter(like='col')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='col')
         .drop('level_1', axis=1)
    )

s.loc[[*zip(u['level_0'], u['col'])]].groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
   id  price1  price2 price_col1 price_col2  price_val
0   1   100.0     NaN     price1     price2      100.0
1   2   200.0     NaN     price2     price1      200.0
2   3   100.0   200.0     price2     price1      200.0
```

Comment: The column names price1 and price2 i would need to retrieve from the columns price_col1 and price_col2.If there is price_col3 column then the value for it and so on.Any idea how can this be achieved?

Comment: Basically, replace `df.filter(like='col')` with `df[['price_col1','price_col2','price_col3']]`. In other words, put all the `price_col` you have there.

Comment: Perfect.Thanks.Edited the question with solution i had created using apply